# Create TMUX instance using PHP on same server

Tags: php, ssh, tmux

I'm trying to start a TMUX session from PHP, I thought it was a simple task but I can't seem to get any success.

The code I am using is

```
shell_exec("tmux new-session -s MyNewSession");
```

but this doesn't do anything.

I've also read about SSH2 connector and have tried this, again with no success

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('xx.xxx.xx.xx', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'XXXXXXXXX');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'tmux new-session -s MyNewSession');
?>
```

Any help would be appreicated.

Thanks
Chris

***** UPDATE *****

If I change the code to:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/tmux tmux new -d -s Test 2>&1');
echo "Done:".$output;
?>
```

I get

```
Done:no server running on /tmp/tmux-33/default
```

So it looks like it's sending the command?

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you add -d so `tmux new -ds myNewSession`?

Comment: Yeah no luck unfortunately

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? `tmux new -dsmysession` will make a new detached session. Are you saying this isn't created at all (so `tmux attach -tmysession` in another terminal window shows an error), or are you expecting it to be somehow attached from PHP?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually using Puty to run tmux ls to list all the sessions and it doesn't appear here

Comment: Are you sure PHP's shell_exec can find tmux? What if you give it the full path to tmux like `/usr/bin/tmux new -dsmysession`? You are running PHP on the same computer as you are running tmux, right?

Comment: Yeah the path is correct, please see my updated question, I'm getting a bit further

Comment: Are you running PHP as the same user as you are checking for a tmux session? Also you have two many tmux in your example it should be `/usr/bin/tmux new` not `/usr/bin/tmux tmux new`.

Comment: That's a good point, I'm logged in as root in PuTTy but not sure when I run the code in PHP, could be on to something. How can I check. Really appreciate your help with this

Comment: The fact tmux is complaining about `tmux-33` means it is running as UID 33, you can find out which user that is by looking at `/etc/passwd`. Are you sure tmux will work as this user without running a specific command (something like `tmux new /bin/sh`)? It may be a system user for PHP with the shell set to `/sbin/nologin` or similar, so tmux will not be able to start the shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210791/discussion-between-walshie1987-and-nicholas-marriott).